# cypher puzzle with chess board

Tags: cipher, chess

[image]

I found this puzzle [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cipher/comments/tlpfms/is_there_anyone_who_can_solve_this/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share) on reddit's cipher community

The answer could be a word or sentence. I thought ABCDE meant the order 12345 and each square could be a letter.